# How to get task status from sub sites in SharePoint master site?

Tags: list, office-365, task-list

I want to fetch task status from sub sites and view in  chart in master site, in master page in need show the status of overall sub site tasks list and in that task completed and not completed list.

How can i implement this in my site ?